# (C++) Does an empty initial statement in a for loop save the previous initialization of the variable in all compilers?

Tags: c++, compilation

Our teacher for our introductory C++ course was speaking on the nature of for loops and how everything within the parentheses can be empty as long as the semicolons are there. My question is, if I were to take two for loops, one after the other, that have the same variable involved in their update statements, is it consistent across all compilers that, once the first for loop is exited, the second will just pick up the value of the variable that came about from the first loop if you keep the initial statement of the second loop empty? Our teacher was uncertain as to whether this interaction was compiler-specific; it worked in VS2017, but she expressed doubt as to whether it would work in earlier versions.

Comment: Can you show some mock code that demonstrates what you're describing? It's a little hard to be sure what you mean with just words.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you're referring to. Please [edit] your question that shows exactly what you're talking about, and include an actual example.

Comment: Please provide [mre], instead of description of code.

Comment: English is not a prices language. Please use code to describe your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your variable is part of the first for loop:

```
for(int x = 0; 10 > x; ++x)
{
}
for(; 20 > x; ++x)
{
}
```

then per the standard 'x' is not even defined for the second loop and the code will not compile. Note that some older compilers don't follow the standard on this point and will behave as in the next example.

If the variable is defined outside the first for loop:

```
int x = 0;
for(; 10 > x; ++x)
{
}
for(; 20 > x; ++x)
{
}
```

then when the second loop is entered 'x' will have the value it had at the time the first loop ended. In no case will 'x' be re-initialized by the second loop, or have some otherwise random value. It will either have the value obtained at the end of the first loop or result in a compilation  error.

Comment: _some older compilers don't follow the standard_ They followed the standard at the time, where the lifetime of `x` extended past the end of the for loop it is declared in. Some were slower to adopt the change that broke the code, and during the transition some supported a flag to control how the declaration would be handled.  You've also left out the case where `int x` is in both loops initializers, which would be helpful for completeness.